# Trouble aligning table on landscape page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to print a large amount of data onto pdf files using LaTeX. I have tabulated this data (a selection of which is in my example below). In order to fit all these data onto the page I have to make it landscape which I have done however there is a problem with my LaTeX file because the table is not positioned into the top left of the page and as a result some of the columns and rows are lost.

Any help on aligning this table to the top left of the page would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[top=0.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.7in, right=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
  \hline
Electron Energy & 0 - 1 & 0 - 2 & 0 - 3 & 0 - 4 & 0 - 5 & 0 - 6 & 0 - 7 & 0 - 8 \\ \hline
  1.0 & 0.6870$\times 10^{-17}$ & 0.2976$\times 10^{-43}$ & 0.6187$\times 10^{-82}$ & 0.2115$\times 10^{-133}$ & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ 
  2.0 & 0.1317$\times 10^{-10}$ & 0.4258$\times 10^{-24}$ & 0.1802$\times 10^{-43}$ & 0.3405$\times 10^{-69}$ & 0.5487$\times 10^{-103}$ & 0.9242$\times 10^{-144}$ & 0.2341$\times 10^{-191}$ & 0.0 \\ 
  3.0 & 0.1501$\times 10^{-08}$ & 0.9479$\times 10^{-18}$ & 0.1095$\times 10^{-30}$ & 0.7885$\times 10^{-48}$ & 0.6775$\times 10^{-71}$ & 0.8495$\times 10^{-99}$ & 0.2238$\times 10^{-131}$ & 0.1846$\times 10^{-165}$ \\ 
  4.0 & 0.1536$\times 10^{-07}$ & 0.1355$\times 10^{-14}$ & 0.2588$\times 10^{-24}$ & 0.3637$\times 10^{-37}$ & 0.7216$\times 10^{-55}$ & 0.2468$\times 10^{-76}$ & 0.2098$\times 10^{-101}$ & 0.6600$\times 10^{-127}$ \\ 
  5.0 & 0.6046$\times 10^{-07}$ & 0.1033$\times 10^{-12}$ & 0.1682$\times 10^{-20}$ & 0.8876$\times 10^{-31}$ & 0.2909$\times 10^{-45}$ & 0.7234$\times 10^{-63}$ & 0.1967$\times 10^{-83}$ & 0.8718$\times 10^{-104}$ \\ 
  6.0 & 0.1482$\times 10^{-06}$ & 0.1828$\times 10^{-11}$ & 0.5765$\times 10^{-18}$ & 0.1582$\times 10^{-26}$ & 0.7245$\times 10^{-39}$ & 0.6763$\times 10^{-54}$ & 0.1854$\times 10^{-71}$ & 0.2223$\times 10^{-88}$ \\ 
  7.0 & 0.2779$\times 10^{-06}$ & 0.1405$\times 10^{-10}$ & 0.3682$\times 10^{-16}$ & 0.1700$\times 10^{-23}$ & 0.2652$\times 10^{-34}$ & 0.1708$\times 10^{-47}$ & 0.6544$\times 10^{-63}$ & 0.2221$\times 10^{-77}$ \\ 
  8.0 & 0.4413$\times 10^{-06}$ & 0.6434$\times 10^{-10}$ & 0.8247$\times 10^{-15}$ & 0.3162$\times 10^{-21}$ & 0.6958$\times 10^{-31}$ & 0.1072$\times 10^{-42}$ & 0.1670$\times 10^{-56}$ & 0.3912$\times 10^{-69}$ \\ 
  9.0 & 0.6279$\times 10^{-06}$ & 0.2085$\times 10^{-09}$ & 0.9191$\times 10^{-14}$ & 0.1828$\times 10^{-19}$ & 0.3152$\times 10^{-28}$ & 0.5744$\times 10^{-39}$ & 0.1595$\times 10^{-51}$ & 0.1006$\times 10^{-62}$ \\ 
  10.0 & 0.8280$\times 10^{-06}$ & 0.5314$\times 10^{-09}$ & 0.6289$\times 10^{-13}$ & 0.4672$\times 10^{-18}$ & 0.4178$\times 10^{-26}$ & 0.5493$\times 10^{-36}$ & 0.1529$\times 10^{-47}$ & 0.1344$\times 10^{-57}$ \\ 
  11.0 & 0.1033$\times 10^{-05}$ & 0.1137$\times 10^{-08}$ & 0.3020$\times 10^{-12}$ & 0.6591$\times 10^{-17}$ & 0.2267$\times 10^{-24}$ & 0.1501$\times 10^{-33}$ & 0.2757$\times 10^{-44}$ & 0.2092$\times 10^{-53}$ \\ 
  12.0 & 0.1238$\times 10^{-05}$ & 0.2135$\times 10^{-08}$ & 0.1112$\times 10^{-11}$ & 0.5959$\times 10^{-16}$ & 0.6301$\times 10^{-23}$ & 0.1604$\times 10^{-31}$ & 0.1418$\times 10^{-41}$ & 0.6489$\times 10^{-50}$ \\ 
  13.0 & 0.1439$\times 10^{-05}$ & 0.3627$\times 10^{-08}$ & 0.3341$\times 10^{-11}$ & 0.3827$\times 10^{-15}$ & 0.1046$\times 10^{-21}$ & 0.8332$\times 10^{-30}$ & 0.2785$\times 10^{-39}$ & 0.5824$\times 10^{-47}$ \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This issue was fixed by putting in the line:

```
\usepackage[top=0.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.7in, right=0.7in]{geometry}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Is your question answered well? If yes you could accept to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even have wider margins fiddling with the font size and the value of `tabcolsep`. I took the opportunity to simplify your code and improve the appearance of the table with `siunitx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, top=0.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{ | S[table-format=1.1] | *{3}{S[table-format=1.4e-2] |}*{5}{S[table-format=1.4e-3] |}}
  \hline
{\makecell{Electron\\Energy}} & {0 -- 1} & {0 -- 2} & {0 -- 3} & {0 -- 4} & {0 -- 5} & {0 -- 6} & {0 -- 7} & {0 -- 8} \\
\hline
  1.0 & 0.6870e-17 & 0.2976e-43 & 0.6187e-82 & 0.2115e-133 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
  2.0 & 0.1317e-10 & 0.4258e-24 & 0.1802e-43 & 0.3405e-69 & 0.5487e-103 & 0.9242e-144 & 0.2341e-191 & 0.0 \\
  3.0 & 0.1501e-08 & 0.9479e-18 & 0.1095e-30 & 0.7885e-48 & 0.6775e-71 & 0.8495e-99 & 0.2238e-131 & 0.1846e-165 \\
  4.0 & 0.1536e-07 & 0.1355e-14 & 0.2588e-24 & 0.3637e-37 & 0.7216e-55 & 0.2468e-76 & 0.2098e-101 & 0.6600e-127 \\
  5.0 & 0.6046e-07 & 0.1033e-12 & 0.1682e-20 & 0.8876e-31 & 0.2909e-45 & 0.7234e-63 & 0.1967e-83 & 0.8718e-104 \\
  6.0 & 0.1482e-06 & 0.1828e-11 & 0.5765e-18 & 0.1582e-26 & 0.7245e-39 & 0.6763e-54 & 0.1854e-71 & 0.2223e-88 \\
  7.0 & 0.2779e-06 & 0.1405e-10 & 0.3682e-16 & 0.1700e-23 & 0.2652e-34 & 0.1708e-47 & 0.6544e-63 & 0.2221e-77 \\
  8.0 & 0.4413e-06 & 0.6434e-10 & 0.8247e-15 & 0.3162e-21 & 0.6958e-31 & 0.1072e-42 & 0.1670e-56 & 0.3912e-69 \\
  9.0 & 0.6279e-06 & 0.2085e-09 & 0.9191e-14 & 0.1828e-19 & 0.3152e-28 & 0.5744e-39 & 0.1595e-51 & 0.1006e-62 \\
  10.0 & 0.8280e-06 & 0.5314e-09 & 0.6289e-13 & 0.4672e-18 & 0.4178e-26 & 0.5493e-36 & 0.1529e-47 & 0.1344e-57 \\
  11.0 & 0.1033e-05 & 0.1137e-08 & 0.3020e-12 & 0.6591e-17 & 0.2267e-24 & 0.1501e-33 & 0.2757e-44 & 0.2092e-53 \\
  12.0 & 0.1238e-05 & 0.2135e-08 & 0.1112e-11 & 0.5959e-16 & 0.6301e-23 & 0.1604e-31 & 0.1418e-41 & 0.6489e-50 \\
  13.0 & 0.1439e-05 & 0.3627e-08 & 0.3341e-11 & 0.3827e-15 & 0.1046e-21 & 0.8332e-30 & 0.2785e-39 & 0.5824e-47 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]